# Not able to add private package in julia

Tags: git, github, julia

I'm trying to add the private git package into my system but I am not able to authenticate the github username password though I'm typing correct one.
Any solutions?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQdXZ.png)

I have tried to update the username and password in credential manager as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outside of Julia, are you able to use clone the repo with your credentials? You might need to enter a token instead, since [password authentication in desktop applications is disabled for GitHub](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/).

Comment: I can add through git bash but could not able to add through Julia repl

Comment: I searched the error message and [this possible solution](https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/RegistryCI.jl/issues/245#issuecomment-629670752) came up. What output do you get if you enter shell mode in the Julia REPL with `;` and enter `git config --show-origin --get-regexp 'credential.*'`?